# fix length re.sub with dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary with all keys three letter long: `threeLetterDict={'abc': 'foo', 'def': 'bar', 'ghi': 'ha' ...}`

Now I need to translate a sentence `abcdefghi` into `foobarha`. I'm trying the method below with `re.sub`, but don't know how to put dictionary in to it:

```
p = re.compile('.{3}') # match every three letters
re.sub(p,'how to put dictionary here?', "abcdefghi")
```

Thanks! (no need to check if input length is multiple of three)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass any callable to `re.sub`, so:

```
p.sub(lambda m: threeLetterDict[m.group(0)], "abcdefghi")
```

[It works!](http://codepad.org/ejK9nQ40)

Comment: I'm not famliar with python and lambda, could you explain a little bit what this is doing? `lambda m: threeLetterDict[m.group(0)]` thanks a lot !

Comment: @Arch1tect: `lambda argument: some expression` is pretty much equivalent to defining a function `def func(argument): return some expression` and then using it wherever the lambda is used. That is to say, it’s an inline function. I hope that makes sense :D

Comment: but `re.sub` requires 3 arguments right? don't you need to pass in `p` ?

Comment: @Arch1tect: That’s the module-level version of `re.sub`, which takes an uncompiled regular expression (as a string). You’ve compiled a regular expression, so to take advantage of it, you call `sub` on the regular expression object. See `help(re.compile(""))`.

Comment: when there is a three-letter in the string that's not in the dictionary, it gives an error because it's not a key... How do I add if statement in lambda to prevent substitution when not found in dictionary? thank you!

Comment: @Arch1tect: `threeLetterDict.get(m.group(0), m.group(0))`

Comment: nice! you are amazing!

Answer (score 3):

A solution that avoids `re` entirely:

```
threeLetterDict={'abc': 'foo', 'def': 'bar', 'ghi': 'ha'}

threes = map("".join, zip(*[iter('abcdefghi')]*3))

"".join(threeLetterDict[three] for three in threes)
#>>> 'foobarha'
```

Answer (score 2):

You might not need to use sub here:

```
>>> p = re.compile('.{3}')
>>> ''.join([threeLetterDict.get(i, i) for i in p.findall('abcdefghi')])
'foobarha'
```

Just an alternate solution :).